# Jquery skip to another page and click on button event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to skip to another page page a click there on button. from index.php something like

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/cart.php?Id=1";
$( "[name='add_to_cart']").click();
window.location.href = "http://localhost/index.php";
```

Problem is, probably, I lost the function scope. If I remove click event, everything works correctly. Thanks

Comment: location.href is refreshing your page an loading the given URL. So everything in the current page is gone. I don't now what is the final approach of your code but this way It cannot work

Comment: Thanks Claus for your answer, the problem is, as you wrote, everything is gone. If I tried window.location.href = "localhost/cart.php?Id=1";window.location.href = "localhost/index.php"; everything works OK, nothing is gone, so I supposed, it should work...

Comment: It won't work. Once you navigate to new page, execution of all code from previous page is stopped.